# how to read the response from a web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website url which gives corresponding city names by taking zip code as input parameter. Now I want to know how to read the response from the site.

This is the link I am using http://zipinfo.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=60680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to Use the HTTPWebRequest object to connect to the site and scrape the information from the response.

Look for html tags or class names that wrap the content you are trying to find, then use either regexes or string functions to get the required data.

Good example [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx):

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually I got the response from the site as HTML, in this City name which I want is returned, now I want to know how to get it from this HTML file?

Comment: I would use the HTML agility pack. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ there is a good example here:  http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/csharp-html-parser-htmlagilitypack/

Answer (score 2):

try this (you'll need to include System.text and System.net)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://zipinfo.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=60680";
Byte[] requestedHTML;
requestedHTML = client.DownloadData(url);

UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string html = objUTF8.GetString(requestedHTML);
Response.Write(html);
```

Comment: you should dispose of the WebClient object if you do this though

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way it to use the light-weight [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) classes in `System.Net` namespace. The following example code will just download the entire response as a string:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   string response = wc.DownloadString("http://zipinfo.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=60680");
}
```

However, if you require more control over the response and request process then you can use the more heavy-weight [`HttpWebRequest Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). For instance, you may want to deal with different status codes or headers. There's an example of using `HttpWebRequest` this in the article [How to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx) on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

Used the WebClient Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to request the page and get the response as a string.

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        String s = wc.DownloadString(DestinationUrl);
```

You can search the response for specific HTML using String.IndexOf, SubString, etc, regular expressions, or try something like the HTML Agility Pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which was created specifically to help parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you better find a good Web Service for this purpose.

and this is an HttpWebRequest example:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://zipinfo.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=60680");
                httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;     
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

                Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HttpWebRequest for receiving content and some tools for parsing html and finding what you need. One of the most popular libs for working with html in c# is HtmlAgilityPack, you can see simple example here: http://www.fairnet.com/post/2010/08/28/Html-screen-scraping-with-HtmlAgilityPack-Library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use a WebClient object, and an easy way to scrape the data is with xpath.